# JS How reference childs method to the parent constructor ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Hi how i can hack this to allow reference the child method to target parents constructor ?
A jsdoc trick or maye a type d.ts
thanks for help, it for vscode.

current behavior
[image]

Target behavior
[image]

i try many hack with jsdoc, knowing vscode can use it, but not work !?
example

```js
    /**@memberof {Parent1|Parent2} */
    doStuff(){ return this.getContext() }
```

maybe someone know a `d.ts` tricks ?

**Source code**

```js
class Child {
    constructor() {}
    /**@memberof {Parent1|Parent2} */
    doStuff(){ return this.getContext() }
};  

class Parent1 extends Child {
    constructor() {super()}
    getContext(){}
}
class Parent2 extends Child {
    constructor() {super()}
    getContext(){}
}
```

**My setting vscode**

```
{
"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": false,
"javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
//"typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition": false,
"typescript.suggest.completeJSDocs": true,
"javascript.validate.enable": true,
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,
}
```

i searching a easy tips plz, i know a way, but it very very ugly and unreadable, i don't like.

Comment: What's the problem with just defining an empty `getContext` method in `Child`? That would be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: if i add a empty `getContext ` method, yes is true, the ref intellisense work fine, but the code execution cant call the parent `getContext `.. 
that's why i can't use this solution

Comment: *"but the code execution cant call the parent getContext'* Can you explain what you mean by that? `this.getContext()` inside `doStuff` will call the corresponding implementations in `Parent1` and `Parent2` if called from an instance of these two classes. Btw usually the base class is the "parent" and the classes that extend the base class are the "children". But I assume when  you say parent you are referring to your `ParentX` classes.

Comment: Ho shit my bad, i really need to sleep !
I am ashamed, i do not know why I thought that the parent did not overload the class.
Here the test , it work fine !! thanks for your time.
https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/0eJuYigmdQoENC5LMa_oP